# Scan an image feed and make them automation

Tags: automation

Which tool is best to scan(Adhar card, driving lience, passport,etc)jpg file and get  text values and save them as PDF or XML or any kind of output

Answer (score 0):

You can try Card Reader http://www.card-reader.com/ , it works great for what you need